# Using my java project jars in sbt android project

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I am new to SBT Android development. I have also no previous experience with sbt.

I have a java project jar. I want to use it in my sbt android project. I dont know where to 
place the jar file as when i do package-debug, the console gives error saying

"not found: jarfile"
(jarfile is the name of the jar file of the java project)

Please suggest where to place the jar file and changes to be made in any of the project files.

My project directory structure is:

```
checkscala--lib_managed
                      scala2.8.1
                           test
------------project
                  boot
                     other
                     scala2.7.7
                     scala2.8.1
                  build
                     target
                        scala2.7.7
                        project.scala
                  plugins
                  build.properties
------------src
                  main
                      assets
                      java
                      res
                      scala
                  test
-----------src_managed
-----------target
-----------tests
```

Comment: For the record, what version of sbt are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the JAR to a `lib/` directory inside the project. See [Library Management](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LibraryManagement) in the wiki, and the Directory Layout section of the [Setup](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup#DirectoryLayout) wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Put the JAR in your project's libs/ directory. Then Build Path -> Library -> Add JAR should allow you to pick the one out of your project. IIRC, this works with Eclipse.

If you decide someday to dump Eclipse, just having your JAR in libs/ is enough -- the command-line build tools will pick it up automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i am using command line and there is no libs folder.

Comment: You can just create it manually.. But I think the name should be lib without the s.

Comment: i created the lib folder in the main directory inside src (source directory) but it didnt recognised the jar. I read it somewhere in sdt site it asks to make some changes to project.scala for library dependencies but could not understand what i should do. The link is  http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/ScalaJars

Comment: The lib folder needs to be in the same directory as the lib_managed folder.